# Returning list filtered inside object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**EDIT**

The complete scenario is, I need to retrieve a list of objects (in this case is Person) and also apply a filter over the collection returned on the property Files, in short terms is I want to get only the persons who has more than one file of a specific type, but also I want to retrieve only this specific file from this query.

Object representation:

```
public class Person(){
  public string name {get; set;}
  public int id {get; set;}
  public List<File> file {get; set;}
}
```

And file entity:

```
public class File(){
  public string name {get; set;}
  public int id {get; set;}
  public int extension {get; set;}
  public int type_file {get; set;}
}
```

**OBS**: i use EF6 and .net framework.

Example:

```
//returning a IQueryable
var t = service.getAll<person>()
   .Where(x => x.id == id)
   .Where(y => y.files.Any(l => l.type_file == 1))
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What does "object filtered by list" mean, and how does it differ from "object with list filtered"? Tell us, in no uncertain terms, what it is you have and what it is you want. Use examples if you have to.

Comment: @Abion47, the explanation of differences. What differs in these terms is this: an object with a filtered list is what has a list with only the data I want, ie if it had 5 objects in that list, after the filter will return an object with a list containing only 3. Which are the ones I desire.
An object filtered by a list is an object that has a list with all 5 data, but this object is only returned if any of these objects meet the lambda. As is the case of the example I passed.

Comment: So, the point of view shouldn't be to search for a `File` of a specific type linked to a specific `Person`? If you're using EF to get a `Person` that have a list of files but change this list to keep only one kind of file, it is possible that when you persist changes to the database all other file types of this person be deleted.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza So as I need to return a list of files I did not find it feasible to do the search through the file. But it is the person who owns the files, since I need to display the data of it and the files belonging to it that have the attachment type. Actually I have managed to do a method that does it, but I do not think it is perfomatico. So I am trying to perform the search through `IQueryable`. I hope this explanation has been made clear, lol

Comment: I can't help but suspect that this might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do with this result?

Comment: @Abion47 The only thing you need to do is pick up a person who has a list of objects of a certain type to view / change. As for the update methods the problem has already been solved, the only problem is to filter the list of data within the person object.

Comment: I got it. But...  Did you have tried my answer (With the @Abion47 notes)?

Comment: I get what you're asking for, and Diego's answer should be sufficient. What I'm trying to gauge is _why_ you are trying to do what you're doing. Either you are constructing entirely new arbitrary fields based on a filter or you are deliberately clearing out existing fields to match said filter, and both of those possibilities are indicative of possible code smell.

Comment: Yes, the answers of the two have cleared my doubts, as the need to accomplish this task is as I said. In order to not create a redundancy in the database of similar tables I created a single table that has a column that performs the task of showing the type of the object, saying if it is an attachment, certificate, etc ... But in a specific case I need to return a person whose list of files is the same as the attachment. I'll post my solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I've created a simple representation of your scenario:

```
static List<Person> GetAllPersons()
{
    var ret = new List<Person>(new [] 
                            { 
                                new Person(){ Id = 10 }, 
                                new Person(){ Id = 4 },
                                new Person(){ Id = 8 }
                            });

    var rnd = new Random();

    foreach(var person in ret)
        for(int i = 0; i <3; i++)
            person.Files.Add(new File() { FileType = rnd.Next(1,3) , Name= "File " + (i + 1).ToString() });

    return ret;
}

class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<File> Files { get;set; }

    public Person()
    {
        Files = new List<File>();
    }
}

class File
{
    public int FileType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I understood your need well, you want to change the `Files` property of the first `Person` that matches to your restrictions.

It would be something like this:

```
public static void Main()
{   
    var Id = 4;
    var all = GetAllPersons();

    var t = all
       .Where(x => x.Id == Id)
       .Select(P => new Person()
                { 
                    Id = P.Id, 
                    Files = P.Files.Where(l => l.FileType == 1).ToList()
                })
       .Where(y => y.Files.Count > 0)
       .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

[*This complete example is available on dotnetfiddle*](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rxMcsR)

But for sure, such kind of logic makes no sense and it's wrong in all possible ways. I'm pretty confident that the problem you're facing is being raised from your confusing logic and it's getting even wrost.

I suggest you to organize your logic before going thru this dangerous way.

Comment: I'll explain my problem better. I have the object person who has a list of files, as explained. But these files have types, which are to differentiate them from each other. And to not need to create several tables in the database of similar objects, the type_file field is used, but in this case I need to get a person with a list that contains only the files of the type attached.

Comment: Instead of first filtering on `y.Files.Any`, it could be more performant to just run the `Select` and then afterward filter out any persons where `y.Files.Count == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `FirstOrDefault`, which will return the first object found by an enumerable (or `null`, if the list is empty*). If you want the list, remove this method call and add `ToList` instead.

```
var t = service.getAll<person>()
               .Where(x => x.id == id)
               .Where(y => y.files.Any(l => l.type_file == 1))
               .ToList();
```

**The more precise answer is that it will return the default value of whatever type the `IEnumerable` represents. For value types, this will be the default value of that type (e.g. 0 for `int`, false for `bool`, etc). For reference types, this will be `null`.*

Comment: I tried it and the result is the same, the object has a list but it is not filtered ....

Comment: @GuilhermeCaixeta That tells me that your filter criteria may be too broad. You're going to need to change your question to include some sample data anyone helping can use to reproduce the problem and come up with a more adequate solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution this problem, i thank you for all you help.

```
        //var person is DTO
        var person= base.Get(id);
        var list = new List<FileDTO>();
        person.file.ForEach(delegate (FileDTO obj)
        {
            if (obj.type_file== (int)TypeFile.Attachment)
            {
                obj.archive = null;
                list.Add(obj);
            }
        });
        person.file = list;
        return person;
```